# Looking for QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS "Group values" tool

Tags: qgis, raster, pixel, grouping, land-use

I have LULC 8 classes. I want to group them in QGIS into five priority score classes in Symbology, just the same as the function in ArcGIS "Group values". But I can't find the same tool in QGIS.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: For what purpose? If styling only you can copy and paste the symbol, or group ranges (i.e. <=20) within singleband pseudocolor , Discrete Interpolation.

Comment: I need to create a map for priority. The problem is that priority score classes are not within the same range. I need to create maps like here :https://www.mdpi.com/2071-1050/14/19/12040

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Open the layer symbology
- Select the classes you wish to group
- Right click to change label for all of the classes at once
- Do the same for the colour
- The classes will appear merged in the legend

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We can use [Reclassify by table](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#reclassify-by-table).

*In this example values 1,2,4 are set to 1; value 3 is set to 2, and all other values are set to null.*
[image]